# I accidentally reset my user data on my phone, can I get it back?

Tags: data-recovery

I forgot my password to my phone and it reset all my data, is there any way possible to get back my lost data?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to get your data back.  This is security, and is by design.  Some of your data will be backed up to the cloud (like your contacts are synced to GMail for instance).  Anything on your device (pictures, SMS history, etc) are lost forever.